# Asking about add value for variable

Tags: rust

Code 1:

```
let x = 1;
let y = x+1;
println!("{}",y);
println!("{}",x);
```

Code 2:

```
let mut s2 = String::from("Tôi tên là");
let s4 = s2;
println!("{}",s4);
println!("{}",s2);
```

Why is x in the code 1 have value but s2 in the code 2 have no value.

Answer (score 4):

By default, when you use a variable in Rust without taking a reference, you *move* the value out of that variable.

```
let mut s2 = String::from("Tôi tên là");
let s4 = s2;
```

Here, `s2` owns the string, then we *move* the string to `s4`. At that time, `s2` no longer has any valid data, since the value it previously owned has moved somewhere else.

Now, the most typical way to get around that is to [clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) the value. Most built-in types can be cloned, and if you clone the value then you get an identical value that shares no direct relationship with the original.

```
let mut s2 = String::from("Tôi tên là");
let s4 = s2.clone();
```

Now `s2` and `s4` both point to two unrelated, valid strings which happen to look exactly the same.

However, the Rust developers were smart enough to realize that this isn't always optimal. For simple types like numbers, it makes no sense to apply ownership (what on earth does it mean to "own" the number 2?). For types where "clone" simply means "copy the value bit-by-bit", we have another trait: [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/marker/trait.Copy.html). Numerical types in Rust implement `Copy`, which effectively puts an automatic `clone` in your code whenever you would move the value. So this

```
let x = 1;
let y = x+1;
```

Since `x` is a "simple" type like a number, Rust does something similar to this automatically

```
let x = 1;
let y = x.clone() + 1;
```

and your original value stays valid.

Strings can't be `Copy`. As I said, `Copy` involves a bitwise copy of the actual data. In Rust, a `String` is a pointer to some allocated memory and a size. Since `String` involves some indirection, its `clone` method has to be smart and do a deep-copy, so we can't use `Copy` to do the simple bitwise copy like we can for numbers.

Answer (score 3):

In the first program the variables are of type `i32`, which is `Copy`. `Copy` types are *copied* rather than moved, so `x` is still useable after using its value.

In the second program `String` is not `Copy`, so when you assign `s2` to `s4` the string is *moved*. Ownership is transferred from `s2` to `s4` and `s2` is no longer readable. You could assign a new string to it but you can't read the one that was moved out.